# Issues with JSF navigation rules using redirect on HTTPS

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, https, navigation

I'm having issues when using `<redirect/`> on navigation rules. My application works on HTTPS and when a navigation rule uses `<redirect/`> the redirect is done to HTTP, not HTTPS. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You should implement a custom [`ConfigurableNavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ConfigurableNavigationHandler.html) that will remap the URL based on the source of the action (I'm assuming here that not all your redirects are to https destinations). As an example:

```
 public class NavigationHandlerTest extends ConfigurableNavigationHandler {

 private NavigationHandlerTest concreteHandler;

 public NavigationHandlerTest(NavigationHandler concreteHandler) {
      this.concreteHandler = concreteHandler;
 }


 @Override
 public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String fromAction, String outcome) 
 {
    //here, check where navigation is going to/coming from and based on that build an appropriate URL.
     if(outcome.equals("someAction"){
        outcome = "https://foo.bar.baz"; //set destination url
          }


     concreteHandler.handleNavigation(context, fromAction, outcome);   

 }


   }
```

Register your implementation in *faces-config.xml*

```
     <application>
        <navigation-handler>com.example.NavigationHandlerTest</navigation-handler>
     </application>
```