# JSF 2 redirect to HTTPS

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2

I've seen these posts: [Issues with JSF navigation rules using redirect on HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636609/issues-with-jsf-navigation-rules-using-redirect-on-https), and [JSF 2 and Post/Redirect/Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416070/jsf-2-and-post-redirect-get), but haven't been able to get what I want to do to work.  I'm trying to redirect to an https page in my app using `ConfigurableNavigationHandler`.  Here's my `handleNavigation`:

```
public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String from, String outcome) {
  System.out.println("outcome: " + outcome);
  if (outcome.startsWith("manageEmail")) {
    outcome = "https://localhost:8081/appmonitor/faces/manageEmail.xhtml";
  }
  System.out.println("outcome: " + outcome);
  parent.handleNavigation(context, from, newOutcome);
}
```

When I click on the link which redirects to "manageEmail", I see that outcome starts as "manageEmail", and changes to my https address, but it doesn't actually redirect there.  I suspect it's trying to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/appmonitor/faces/https://localhost:8081/appmonitor/faces/manageEmail.xhtml`.  If this is what is in fact happening, is there any way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the external response and give back a redirect command?

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.sendRedirect(outcome);
```

Comment: I didn't realize I had to do that.  I assumed that `parent.handleNavigation(context, from, newOutcome);` was going to take care of that for me.  Now I know -- Thank you!